# Google Sheets - Multiply field by field three to the left

Tags: google-sheets

My title might not be very specific, so I'm going to try to explain a little better.
The sheet is divided into a name(Column A), containing a certain number of values(Column B), that get added together to a total in Column C. Furthermore, Column D, E and F contains the values I want the Total in Column C multiplied by. These first columns A to F I just fill in manually, but I would like a function to calculate the Columns I've called x, y and z total (G, H and I).
I see a pattern in this, I just can't figure out the syntax to get Sheets to see it aswell.
The pattern I'm invisioning is for each row, I want column G, H and I to take the value 3 fields to their left, and multiply it by Column C, at their row number.
Is this somehow achievable? I tried finding a solution online but I guess I don't know how to word myself.

Here's a picture to maybe make everything a little clearer
[image]

This would save me alot of time, given that I have over a hundred different rows this calculation needs to be performed on...
If something is not clear, please feel free to write a comment. I'll be following this thread quite liberally.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Is there any single function I can copy and paste into the empty fields in Column G, H and I, that multiplies the field three to its left, by the field at their own row number in Column C?
To basically write this as pseudo code; This field = field three left, same row * field column c, same row

Comment: updated my answer, let me know if it helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have this formula on the first xTotal:

- cell `G2`: `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(C2:C),C2:C*D2:D,))`
- cell `G2`: `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(C2:C),C2:C*E2:E,))`
- cell `G2`: `=ARRAYFORMULA(if(len(C2:C),C2:C*F2:F,))`

I created a sheet with the same results you had before, but this time you don't need vertical columns, just say in the `# of Values` column how many numbers you should have below. You just need to input the values with the grey columns.

**Note:** This is assuming you will always have growing vertical numbers like 1,2,3,4,5. In the new sheet you just need to set 5 in the column and it will calculate the result.

Please make a copy of this sheet and edit as you wish.

[Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QUql8ox9cXn3HJS1-lSfMgdWwfw2YApuAhiyc-jsz24/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @JeyesElite, I updated my answer with a sheet for you, if it helps then it would be great

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single, simpler formula for this in cell `G2`

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(if(C2:C="",,C2:C*{D2:D,E2:E,F2:F}))
```